# Remove precompiler directive from .h header file

Tags: c, conditional-compilation, precompile, precompiled-headers

I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to solve.

Suppose the following typedef struct into a test.h header file:

```
typedef struct example_struct {
    #ifdef CONFIG_A
    int A;
    #endif;

    int B;
} example_struct_t;
```

I am compiling the code using this header file passing CONFIG_A to the GCC with -D option. This way I am able to include A member to the struct or remove if not needed for a given use case.

Now suppose I generate a shared library (.so) and I would like to distribute it. So, I have the .so library and the headers with precompiler directives. The problem is that I would like not to include the -DCONFIG_A in the program using the library, I mean, I would need to hold the options employed at the library compilation time not only in the source files (.c) but also in the header. That is to say, if a compile the library with -DCONFIG_A option I suppose that program using the library shouldn't include that option in compilation time.

Are the precompiled headers the solution for this problem or is there any other alternative (avoiding include a config.h header in every files defining precompiler directives)?

Thank you so much for the guidance.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem: Question how to fix a wrong solution for a problem. And pick the language: C or C++?

Comment: For C++ there is [the One Definition Rule (aka ODR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). If `CONFIG_A` is defined when compiling some [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) but not for others, you have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: When installing the library you can install also a `mylibrary.pc` file with the proper preprocessor options. Then instruct your users to use `pkg-config --cflags mylibrary`.

Comment: The question mentions ".c" as the source file - meaning this isn't a c++ question

Comment: The first question you really should be asking is why the structure needs to be exposed and visible to use your shared object at all.  Exposing internal implementation details like this means you can't change your library without forcing every binary using your library to be recompiled.  It also opens you up to some really *interesting* bugs should someone compile the structure in a way that results in a different size and/or alignment than one your library expects.  Ideally, things like `struct` definitions should not be visible to library users - they should interact only via a defined API.

Comment: As UKMonkey said, is a C question.
Andrew I'am totally agrre with you, I would like not to expose my structs in header files to force user to iteract with them via the API, but where can I define them? I mean, I need them to be in a header file in order to be included and used  by a third party program.

Answer (score 0):

You can "generate" the code for the structure definition and ship the generated definition alongside the corresponding library.  One idea is to keep your structures in a header with no `#include`s, in which case you can run the C preprocessor on them to get a file with no `#ifdef`s (which you can then use to build and ship).

Another way is to do something special in your build system.  For example `CMake` has `#cmakedefine` which you can use inside a C or C++ source file and then generate code from that.